# Get clicked element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, sliding

I tried some jQuery and I want to figure out how to get a sliding menu working.
I have a class "dropdown" on a `<ul>`. A submenu displays for all the `<a>`'s I click. The submenu `<ul>`'s have class "sub-menu" appointed to them.

I have gotten quite far in making this work. Now all I want to make sure is that when submenu-items are clicked they behave as they would normally. This is now prevented by preventDefault. Neat function, but I want to disable it for sub-menu `<a>`'s.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown > li').click(function () {
        var $el = $('ul', this); // element to toggle
        $('.dropdown > li > ul').not($el).slideUp();
        $(this).find('.sub-menu ').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.dropdown > li').children().children().click(function (e) {
        return false;
    });
    $(".dropdown > li > a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I added the preventDefault to avoid the normal routine on the main menu, and I disabled the slideToggle action for the sub-menu.

Now I would like add the default behaviour for the submenu `<a>`'s. They are doing nothing at the moment.

EDIT:
I found the "not" bit of JQuery and I am trying to get that to work (as I haven't had a satisfying answer yet). What I want is to exclude all 's that belong to the class "sub-menu" from the function that slides the sub-menu's. The syntax I came up with is:

```
$('.dropdown > li').not('ul.sub-menu > li > a').click(function() {
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I click an  that is within  it still performs the function. So how would I rephrase the code above for the function above to always perform except when the  is within a ?

Comment: can you do a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yep, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Pgm7G/

Comment: just take out the crazy children children bit and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/Pgm7G/1/

Comment: nope. What happens than is that when the submenu items are clicked, they slide away. I want them to stay where they are and do default behaviour. Not the function.

Comment: what? when the submenu items are clicked you navigate to the linked page as default behaviour

Comment: Nope. They should load a popup, but this is just an example.

Comment: if they have to load a popup you have to return false at the end of the function that loads the popups and handles their click event

Comment: Would you suggest: <a href="javascript:popup('http://www.google.com',500,300);return false">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something that seems to work as I want it to. In the following code (after all "other" subitems have slid up) a check is made whether the current menu-item contains a sub-item that is visible. If not it is slid up, else down.

```
$(function() {
 $('ul.dropdown > li > a').click(function () {
  var $el = $('ul', this);
  $('.dropdown > li > ul').not($el).slideUp();
  if(  $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu ').is(":visible"))
  {$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu ').slideUp();}
  else
  {$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu ').slideDown();}
 });

 $(".dropdown > li > a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

});

Because it explicitly targets the a element of class "dropdown" (i.e. the main-menu-items), the default behaviour of the subitems is untouched. (Because of that, the this.parent() is needed to look for sub-menu-items.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do for first or any specified element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-item').bind('click', function () {
        if($(this).children('ul').length =0){      
            return false;      
        }
       else{
           $(this).children('.sub-menu ').slideToggle();
           return false;
       }    
    });
});
```

IF **HTML code** is like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
      ITEM1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
      ITEM2
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" >
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">
                  SUBITEM1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">
                 SUBITEM2
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For **DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/Pgm7G/16/

Comment: it's `:eq(0)` if you use it inside the selector string

Comment: yes its :eq(0) OR can be used :nth-child(0) like this thanx for correction @David

Comment: I saw you edit and saw the JFiddle. The problem is that when the sub-menu-items are clicked they slide up. They should stay. Not slide.

Comment: Thanks, but still not there. It is exactly how I want it, but for one thing. I added two alert boxes to the subitems. I would like to see those when the sub-items are clicked. But for the rest everything should stay as is. see http://jsfiddle.net/Pgm7G/23/

Answer (score 0):

As i commented,

```
$('.dropdown > li').children().children().click(function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

is selecting the submenu links and the `return false` has the same effect of `e.preventDefault()`.

just take out that bit

Comment: As commented above: the submenu-items are now performing the function when I take that part out. I don't want them to slide. I want them to always stay where they are when clicked and perform there default behaviour. They thing is: the sub-items should open a popup...

Comment: to prevent sliding on submenu click attach the event to the `a` instead of the `li` http://jsfiddle.net/Pgm7G/5/

Comment: When I do  $('.dropdown > li > a').click(function() , the submenus slide up but never down again...